# How do I prevent ShowDialog from stealing focus from other applications?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In my application, the `ShowDialog()` method of a custom form is called after some work is done. The problem is that if the user switches to another application while my application is doing its work, the dialog steals focus to that application, and this can lead to unpredictable behavior. The expected behavior would be the dialog showing in my application foreground, but not on top of another application, and have my application's Taskbar item to blink.

Is there a way to prevent the `ShowDialog()` method from stealing focus? Or should I use another approach?

Comment: `ShowDialog()`, as well as the message boxes, receives the focus when appeared. You can consider using just `Show()` and putting `.Enabled = False` for the background form. That will do the trick.

Comment: I use the returned ShowDialogResult so I need to use ShowDialog. If I use MsgBox, the focus isn't stolen from other apps

Comment: You could try the overloaded form of `ShowDialog` [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w61zzfwe.aspx). It may work; I haven't tried it. Using `Show` won't create a modal dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I guess this is the intended behavior of ShowDialog, because they expected it to be called after some action by the user (eg clicking on a button). If there isn't any hacking, I guess I'll have to implement some custom way to return a DialogResult using Show()

Answer (score 2):

Use Form.ShowWithoutActivation property (override it in your class to return true). This way you can still use ShowDialog().

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showwithoutactivation(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), you use [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to show a form `stealing focus` as you say. And [Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to show without stealing focus. I'm not sure if it's the same in VB.NET.

Comment: Should be the same, it's all .NET.

Comment: that was my thoughts exactly.

Comment: I use the returned DialogResult so I need to use ShowDialog instead of Show.

Comment: DialogResult is the result from a MessageBox. This is all you can do with MessageBox and DialogResult: http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property

```
me.TopMost = false
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx)

Comment: I tried setting TopMost to false but the ShowDialog method probably overrides this property

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this you probably have to use Show.  Keep your own property on the form

DialogResult Result;

Probably default it to cancel so if the form is closed it will be treated as a cancel.  Then you only need to set it when the user clicks OK.